# Expected runtime of Previous Larger Element algorithm

Tags: algorithm, probability

The following algorithm returns the previous larger element of an array. It is from page 11 of [these](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2013/cmsc451/cmsc451-lects.pdf) notes.

```
// Input: An array of numeric values a[1..n]
// Returns: An array p[1..n] where p[i] contains the index of the previous
// larger element to a[i], or 0 if no such element exists.
previousLarger(a[1..n]) 
    for (i = 1 to n)
        j = i-1;
        while (j > 0 and a[j] <= a[i]) j--;
        p[i] = j;
return p
```

My homework question is: Given input sequence `{a1,...,an}` is a random permutation of the set `{1,...,n}`, what is the expected running time?

I think this requires some sort of probabilistic analysis, but I need some hints since I have only done worst-case analysis in the past. I'm trying to find a formula for the cost of the `j-loop` for a given i (1 + the number of times we do operation `j--`), then sum that formula up from 1 to n.

What does "expected" mean? I don't really know how to interpret this.

Comment: another approach: there are n! possible arrays, and that the answer will be:
E[Runtime] = sum i=1,...,N!  { Runtime(i) } / N!

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Heuster's answer:

1) You know that the answer is between O(n) and O(n^2). This is just to check the final result.

2) The expected number of steps for element `i` would indeed be:

```
sum_{k=1}^i 1 / (k+1)
= O(log i)
```

3) You have to sum all those number over i. This gives you:

```
sum_{i=1}^n O(log i)
= O(n log n)
```

What I did is not rigorous at all but you can prove derive it. O(n log n) is between O(n) and O(n^2) so it seems a good candidate :)

Comment: Thanks, it has been years since I worked on randomized algorithms, so I had totally forgotten that the harmonic numbers are simply discrete logarithm values. I completed my answer based on that information. +1 for pointing it out :-)

Answer (score 0):

For and arbitrary index `i`, what is the chance that `a[i-1] > a[i]` (in other words, the inner while loop will take one step)? That one is easy: all elements in `a` are different, so `P(a[i-1] > a[i]) = P(a[i] > a[i-1]) = 1/2`.

Now, look at the case that the inner while loop would need to take two steps. That is, `a[i-2] > a[i] > a[i-1]`. This is exactly one of the 6 permutations of 3 elements, so the chance is `1 / 3! = 1 / 6`.

Let's generalize this and assume that the inner while loop would need to take `k` steps. We consider the sublist `a[i-k], a[i-k+1], ..., a[i]`. We know that `a[i-k]` is the maximum element of this sublist and `a[i]` the second largest (otherwise, the inner loop would have stopped sooner). The order of the elements in between is irrelevant. The chance that we take `k` steps is thus `1 / (k + 1) * 1 / k = 1 / (k * (k + 1))`. Note that this indeed degeneralizes to `1/2` for `k = 1` and `1/6` for `k = 2`.

The chance that no element before `a[i]` is larger is simply `1 / i` (`a[i]` is the maximum element in that sublist). In that case, the inner loop would need `i` steps.

The expected number of steps for element `i` would be (sum of probability times value):

```
Sum[{k, 1, i} k * 1 / ((k * (k + 1))] + i / i 
    = Sum[{k, 1, i} 1 / (k + 1)] + 1
    = H_{i+1}
```

where `H_{i}` is the ith harmonic number, which is the discrete variant of `log i`. That is, the number of steps for element `i` is `Θ(i)`.

What is remaining now is sum over all `i` to find the expected running time. With the exact value (`H_{i+1}`) this doesn't lead to a nice expression, see [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%5Bsum%5B1%20/%20%28k%2b1%29,%20%7Bk,%201,%20i%7D%5D%2b1,%20%7Bi,%200,%20n-1%7D%5D).

The standard way to proceed, however, is to continue with the approximated `log i`. Clearly, `log 0 + log 1 + ... + log n-1` is less than `n log n`. Now, consider the last half of the sum:

```
log n/2 + log n/2+1 + ... + log n-1 > n/2 log n/2
                                    = n/2 (log n - log 2)
                                    = Ω(n log n)
```

Therefore, the expected running time is `Θ(n log n)`.